# Unable to scroll Visualforce page in Safari on iOS

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have created a custom Visualforce page in my Salesforce org.  The page is visible to both standard Salesforce users and users of a Salesforce Community configured on the same org (the standard Salesforce users aren't using the Community to view the page).  The page is longer than the content area in the browser.

When the Community User is logged into the community and views the page, the User is able to scroll the page.  When the standard Salesforce user logs in and views the same page, the page is unable to scroll.

I have looked at the first related story about being unable to scroll and:

- The page only uses the  Visualforce tag; everything else is HTML;
- The viewport meta tag has similar content (and using the exact content did not fix the issue either).

Comment: Did you set both `showHeader` and `standardStylesheets` to false?

Comment: Yes.  No HTML or body tags, header and standard stylesheets set to false.